# Rotation of angular momentum states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

Consider a rotation of cartesian coordinate axes xyz given by $$R(\alpha \beta \gamma)= e^{-i\alpha J_z}e^{-i\beta J_y}e^{-i\gamma J_z}$$
Let us now consider transformation of angular momentum eigenstates $\left|jm\right>$ under this rotation.
\begin{align*}
\left<jm'|R(\alpha\beta\gamma)|jm\right>&=\left<jm'|e^{-i\alpha J_z}e^{-i\beta J_y}e^{-i\gamma J_z}|jm\right>\\
&=e^{-i\alpha m' } d^j_{m'm}(\beta) e^{-i\gamma m}
\end{align*}
where $d_{m'm}^j(\beta)=\left<jm'|e^{-i\beta J_y}|jm\right>$.

Now $d_{m'm}^j(\beta)$ has the property: $$d_{m'm}^j(-\beta)=(-1)^{m'-m}d_{m'm}^j(\beta)$$
Can anyone please explain by simple arguments why this property should hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number ways to see that this needs to be the case. To begin with, it should be clear that you would expect *some* sort of simple relationship between the $z$-basis matrix elements for a rotation by $\beta$ around the $y$ axis, and those of its inverse. I normally leave it at that: you expect some nice relation, so... is that it? cool, let's move on.

However, you asked for something more specific, so let's have a look at that.

The simplest route I can think of is realizing that a rotation by $-\beta$ about $\hat{\mathbf e}_y$ is exactly the same as a rotation by $\beta$ about $-\hat{\mathbf e}_y$, and that this is, in turn, the same as a rotation by $\beta$ about $\hat{\mathbf e}_y$ sandwiched between two rotations by $\pi$ about $\hat{\mathbf e}_z$. Thus, on geometrical grounds, you expect that
$$
e^{+i\beta J_y}=e^{+i\pi J_z}e^{-i\beta J_y}e^{-i\pi J_z},
$$
and the relation you want follows immediately once you take the appropriate matrix element.

Comment: This is a nice and intuitive way to see it. Thanks!